# Add line break when reading text from xml

Tags: android

In my application, I'm parsing a local xml file, store the read texts in an array list and set the texts in text views. the problem is that I can't use the \n sequence to get a line break in the text view. The text view will display the \n characters as any other text. If I try to use the html tag 
, I'm getting a runtime error.

Is there a way to specify the line breaks when reading the text from an xml file?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

instead "\n" now use "newline"

Comment: How shoud I use the System.getProperty("line.separator") method? I am not writing the file programatically.

Comment: set TextView's singleLine property false then textView.setText(xmldata + newline +xmldata);

Comment: You mean that i have to split the xml text? There is no way of passing the whole text?

Comment: depends ion mechanism, here you can try with this text.replaceALL("\n",newline);